# Can I use Windows Error images (Red circle with white cross) in my WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a custom error message box for my project. In the View for this, I have an image which should be used for message type (Error, Info, Warn, etc.) which Windows already has built-in images for. Is there a way I can use these images via setting the source property in XAML programatically?

(I have been using [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081930/Custom-Message-Box-in-WPF-XAML) for making the box, if it helps)

Comment: If you chose to copy the icons into a folder for your use you may use the program "IconsExtract" by NirSoft or similar, an the directories the icons are stored are listed on this site: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons the icons are usually stored in dll or exe files for example %systemroot%\system32\imageres.dll. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works, if you want to do it the nasty way (it's the only way I know to get the "WinForms style" images):

```
var sii = new SHSTOCKICONINFO();
sii.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHSTOCKICONINFO));    
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(SHGetStockIconInfo(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_WARNING, SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON, ref sii));
ImageSource = Icon.FromHandle(sii.hIcon).ToImageSource();
```

Note:  I chose not to use this, and instead just included images in my resources to use as I needed them.

Comment: Do you happen to know where the typical Windows images would be located, to make a copy of?

Comment: I do not.  There are system DLLs from which you can extract them, but it's all a bit tedious.  Better off finding something in a library already, or take the advice on the duplicate post(s).

Comment: Aye you answered before the duplicate post appeared. Thank you for the time, but will likely use the duplicate's